# Flutter - Can't change child state from parent widget

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-widget

**Problem**:

I have a parent widget `SnippetTestEditor` and a stateful child widget `NoteTab`. If a button in the parent widget is pressed, the child widget should get updated.

Both classes have a bool `_editMode`. I pass the bool from the parent widget to the child widget via the constructor. From my understandig, I need to call `setState()` in the parent widget and change the bool within `setState()`. This change should automatically be reflected in the child widget. But it's not....

So how can I get the child widget to change?

**Code:**

```
class _SnippetTestEditorState extends State<SnippetTestEditor> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  bool _editMode = true;
  ...

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _tabs = List();
    _tabNames = List();

    List<CodeSnippet> codeSnippets = this.widget._note.codeSnippets;
    for(CodeSnippet snippet in codeSnippets){
      _tabs.add(CodeTab(_editMode);

    ...
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    ...
    body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: _tabs
    ),
    ...
    actions: <Widget>[ 
       IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.check),
          onPressed: (){
            setState(() {
              _editMode = false;
            });
          },
        )
    ...
```

```
class CodeTab extends StatefulWidget{

  bool _editMode;

  CodeTab(this._editMode);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => CodeTabState();

}

class CodeTabState extends State<CodeTab> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return this.widget._editMode ? ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `_editMode` value is passed to `CodeTab` only once, inside `initState()`. So, even though the `build` method is called multiple times, the `CodeTab` instances in `_tabs` do not get updated.

you should move the code to create tabs in a method inside the state class:

```dart
getTabs(){
 List<CodeSnippet> codeSnippets = widget._note.codeSnippets;
 for(CodeSnippet snippet in codeSnippets){
   _tabs.add(CodeTab(_editMode);
 return _tabs;
}
```

and use `getTabs()` in build:

```dart
 body: TabBarView(
  controller: _tabController,
  children: getTabs(),
 ),
```

If you have any doubts in this solution, Let me know in the comments.